# Question regarding the definition of a decreasing function

Tags: calculus

We know that $f(x)$ is decreasing if $f(x) > f(y)$ for all $x<y$

## Question:

Consider the interval $[\pi/2, \pi ]$. Clearly, in this interval $\sin x > \cos x $. We know $f(x) = \cos x$ decreases on this interval, therefore by definition, we must have

$$ \cos ( \sin x)  < \cos ( \cos x ) $$

or in other words that $\cos ( \cos x ) - \cos ( \sin x ) > 0$ for all $x \in [ \pi /2 , \pi ]$. However, when we plot the function, we observe that this is not always true. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple : $\cos$ is decreasing on $[\frac{\pi}{2} , \pi]$. For $x \in [\frac{\pi}{2} , \pi]$, do $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ lie in this interval?

Indeed, no. So you cannot conclude that $\cos(\cos x) > \cos(\sin x)$, because $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ don't belong in $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$, even if $x$ does.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\cos x$ decreases in the given interval but you cannot apply this to the inequality $\sin x >\cos x$. This because the numbers $\sin x $ and $\cos $ are not in $[\frac {\pi} 2,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

The values of $\sin x$ vary between $1$ and $0$, and $\cos x$ vary between $0$ and $-1$. So it makes no sense to look at the cosine of those values and compare to the behavior in the interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$